# Some JVM flags stop backgrounded process unexpectedly

Tags: linux-kernel, java, background-process

I've been running a local Minecraft server for my kids at home, and as more have joined, lag has become a problem...and lately, actual game crashes (when a single game "tick" takes more than 60s, the game automatically shuts down the JVM).

Experimenting with some recommended JVM flags has resulted in the kernel automatically (and silently!) stopping the background java process, and I'm not sure why.

The host machine is a quad-core i7 (8-threads) with 32GB RAM running Fedora 31.

Java is Oracle's SE runtime:

```
java version "1.8.0_231"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_231-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.231-b11, mixed mode)
```

Originally, the working game launch command string was:

```
java -Xms2G -Xmx4G -server -XX:+UseG1GC -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=false -jar minecraft_server.1.15.2.jar nogui &
```

Adding the recommended JVM flags for optimizing performance resulted in the OS silently stopping the background java process:

```
java -Xms10G -Xmx10G -server -XX:+UseG1GC -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=false -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch  -XX:G1NewSizePercent=30 -XX:G1MaxNewSizePercent=40 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=8M -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:G1HeapWastePercent=5 -XX:G1MixedGCCountTarget=8 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=15 -XX:G1MixedGCLiveThresholdPercent=90 -XX:G1RSetUpdatingPauseTimePercent=5 -XX:SurvivorRatio=32 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1 -Dusing.aikars.flags=true -Daikars.new.flags=true -jar minecraft_server.1.15.2.jar nogui &
```

I verified that the XMS/XMX changes weren't responsible by testing them independently using my original JVM flags set.

Executing this command results in the JVM launching and the game server beginning to initialize, then suddenly stopping.  The OS reports: **[1] Stopped**

I can manually bring it to the foreground and it resumes execution normally (it also works fine when I launch it in the foreground).  Any attempt to return it to the background results in the process automatically stopping again.

However, if I run the same command string using *nohup*, then process behaves as expected...that is to say, the game's java process actually runs in the background.

So my question for any kernel and/or Java gurus, what in my JVM flags is causing the OS to stop the process when it's launched in the background?

**EDIT - Additional info**

Parsing through the *nohup.out* file, I do see this error that does NOT occur when launching the jvm process in the foreground.

```
[04:12:38] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting minecraft server version 1.15.2
[04:12:38] [Server thread/INFO]: Loading properties
[04:12:38] [Server thread/INFO]: Default game type: SURVIVAL
[04:12:38] [Server thread/INFO]: Generating keypair
[04:12:38] [Server console handler/ERROR]: Exception handling console input
java.io.IOException: Bad file descriptor
        at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at wd$2.run(SourceFile:110) [minecraft_server.1.15.2.jar:?]
[04:12:38] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting Minecraft server on *:25512
[04:12:38] [Server thread/INFO]: Using epoll channel type
```

Comment: The background java process may try to read from its stdin and gets a `SIGTTIN` signal (which stops it by default). The default `nohup` on GNU/Linux redirects its stdin from an unreadable file (`/dev/null` opened in write-only mode). Start your java process in foreground, and see it _asks_ you anything.

Comment: I'm no java guru, but I don't think that any of those garbage collection tweaks should cause it to stop or try to read from its stdin. I have no idea what those `-Daikars.new.flags=true -Dusing.aikars.flags=true` (in the "optimized" version) do.

Comment: I wasn't sure about those "aikars" flags, either, so I tried removing them.  Same effect.

Also, the game server launch doesn't take any console input.  Executing it in the foreground just launches the game server normally.

Comment: The error you get is because of the nohup redirecting the stdin from `/dev/null` opened in write-only mode, as I already said. So java really DOES try to read from stdin. Try removing the options one by one and see which one is causing it.

Comment: I'll chase down the EBADF error, but I'm still nonplussed as to why I can launch the java process in the foreground normally, but when I attempt to background it (CTRL-Z), the OS stops the process immediately.

Comment: I've already explained you in the 1st comment why that happens, and why you get an EBADF error with nohup (trying to read from a non-readable fd = EBADF). From the extra flags you give in the second command, only the `-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow` _looks_ like having something to do with the "console". Start with removing that option.

Comment: Again, much appreciated, mosvy.  Turns out the game launcher I set up long ago is instantiating the JVM using *screen* rather than *nohup.*

Guess who's feeling like a noob right now?